# PHP - displaying last 3 SQL rows in a table (not working)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to develop a user profile system on my website, with the previous 3 posts made by the user. I can get it to select the previous 3 records, but it will only display one of them. Am I just being stupid because I'm trying to code at 2am?

```
<?php                       
    $q = "SELECT * FROM blog_cmt WHERE uid=".$profile_uid." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3";
    $r = $db->query($q);                                
    $c = $r->num_rows;                              
?>

<table class="table">
    <?php
    while($post = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
        $pid = $post['pid'];
        $q = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE pid=".$pid;
    $r = $db->query($q);
    $blog = $r->fetch_assoc();
    $title = $blog['title'];
    $date = timeSince(strtotime($post['date']));
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.my_domain.co.uk/thread.php?id=<?php echo $pid; ?>">Commented on <?php echo $title; ?></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $date; ?> ago
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You keep overriding $r to a single post ID: $r = $db->query($q);

Comment: So use a different variable name each time?

Comment: of course - you're in a "while" loop - so if $r originally has 3 records, then you override $r to a single record, next loop on the while will have already used $r

Comment: I need that line to grab some data from a different table. I gave each variable in the second query a different name and it fixed it - thanks!

Comment: @Phil - not the best comment I must say. - you need to write better code and you would have seen this a mile away.. I'll post an answer

Comment: I can accept in 3 minutes - thanks again for the help :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$profile_post_qry = "SELECT * FROM blog_cmt WHERE uid=".$profile_uid." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3";
$profile_posts = $db->query($profile_post_qry);

$profile_post_count = $profile_posts->num_rows;

?>

<table class="table">

<?php

while($post = $profile_posts->fetch_assoc()) {

$pid = $post['pid'];
$blog_qry = "SELECT * FROM blog WHERE pid=".$pid;
$blog_info = $db->query($blog_qry);
$blog = $blog_info->fetch_assoc();
$title = $blog['title'];
$date = timeSince(strtotime($post['date']));

?>

<tr>
<td>
    <a href="http://www.my_domain.co.uk/thread.php?id=<?php echo $pid; ?>">Commented on <?php echo $title; ?></a>
</td>
<td>
    <?php echo $date; ?> ago
</td>
</tr>

<?php
```